# Space $Y\subset C[0,1]$ consisting of all $x \in C[a,b]$ such that $x(a) = x(b)$ is complete.

Tags: metric-spaces

This is problem from kreyszig functional analysis:  I have to show that space $Y\subset C[a,b]$ consisting of all $x \in C[a,b]$ such that $x(a) = x(b)$ is complete.

I am struggling with this problem for over an hour. Even I am not able to figure out such space.I need help to solve this problem.

Edited:

Thanks

Comment: $a = 0$, $b=1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope it's ok to post a more detailed version, maybe OP (or other users) will benefit from it.

$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert{#1}\rVert}\newcommand{\abs}[1]{|{#1}|}$I
suppose you work with sup norm
$\norm{x}=\sup_{t\in[a,b]}\abs{x(t)}$, since this is the usual
meaning of $C(X)$.

We know that $C[a,b]$ is complete (it is a Banach space). Recall
that a subspace of a complete metric space is complete if and only
if it is closed. (A proof of this result can be found at [proofwiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subspace_of_Complete_Metric_Space_is_Closed_if_and_only_if_Complete).) So it suffices to show that $Y$ is closed in
$C[0,1]$.

Now I think that it is quite clear that if a sequence of functions
$(x_n)$ converges to $x$ uniformly and $x_n(a)=x_n(b)$, then
$x(a)=x(b)$. (Even pointwise convergence would be sufficient for
this last argument.)

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I was confused with how to show $x(a) = x(b)$?

Answer (score 3):

What you probably already know: $C[0,1]$ is complete.

What you can show if you haven't yet:

- $Y$ is a closed subspace of $C[0,1]$.
- A closed subspace of a complete space is complete.

Comment: How to show $Y$ is closed in $C[0,1]$? I am sorry,I have just started reading metric space so my question may sound elementary.

Comment: @srijan Whenever $x_n\in Y$ converges to $x\in C[0,1]$, you must prove $x\in Y$.

Comment: @srijan: Are you familiar with the fact that if $A$ is a subset of a metric space $X$, then $A$ is closed if and only if for each sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ that converges to some $x\in X$, $x$ is also in $A$?

Comment: @JonasMeyer yes I am familiar with this fact.

Comment: @srijan: Good; I recommend proving that $Y$ is closed using this sequence method, as mentioned in AD.'s first comment and elaborated by Martin's answer.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Thank you very much sir. I got valuable information form here.

Comment: @JonasMeyer BTW $Y$ *is* a subspace.